# How to add SQLCLR to AWS with certificate?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, sqlclr

I have created a SQLCLR functions works with RabbitMQ.
Added them to SQL Server as described here
https://nielsberglund.com/2017/07/01/sqlclr-and-certificates/
using certificate: created it, added to database, created Login etc.
It works fine.
Can add my SQLCLR functions to AWS RDS SQL Server database using the same way?
In particular SQL Server I do this way:

```
use master;
IF exists(select * from sys.syslogins where name = N''login21'') DROP LOGIN [login21];
IF exists(select * from sys.certificates where name = N''login21Cert21'')    DROP CERTIFICATE [login21Cert21];
CREATE CERTIFICATE [login21Cert21] FROM BINARY = 
0x30820....;
CREATE LOGIN [login21] FROM CERTIFICATE [login21Cert21];
GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO [login21];
```

But the question is if it is possible to add certificate/login to AWS RDS SQLServer master database?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: No , I afraid :-) ,  just asked to be sure it is possible. I have no yet access to AWS

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick google search (literally "RDS CLR") and the first page is a [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html) to AWS' documentation which says:

> Common Runtime Language (CLR). On RDS for SQL Server 2016 and lower versions, CLR is supported in SAFE mode and using assembly bits only. CLR isn't supported on RDS for SQL Server 2017 and higher versions. For more information, see Common Runtime Language Integration in the Microsoft documentation."

Also, regarding your comment of not trying it because you don't have access to AWS, *everyone* has access. To try out what you're proposing would take about five minutes on a personal account. I'd guess that it would cost less than $1 USD and certainly less than $10.

Comment: Hi Ben, it is not so today. Please look at https://support.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/bestpractice-rds/rds_04_0009.html

Comment: Can you tell me how the articles that we've respectively cited contradict? If the example in the article that you cited was run against SQL 2016 or older it would work and *should* work according to the AWS docs.